# AJAX Download large file and POST to other domain

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm having issues with a small script I'm creating. It downloads large(ish) files from one domain (around 15Mb each) using AJAX, and I want to then upload / post them to another domain also using AJAX. Downloading isn't a problem. I've added a nice download status bar, and have checked that the responseText is stoed in a variable, which works fine.

The script then attempts to use AJAX POST to upload this data to another domain. I've set the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin:' header on my domain, and the domains can both 'talk' to each other fine. Is it the AJAX that's not letting me upload such a large chunk of data? It actually crashes the browser.

Any ideas on how I should handle large files downloading then uploading straight away, would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I'm trying to download a file from domain A to the users computer (but not save the file, just store it in a variable), then upload it straight to domain B.

Thanks! - Dan.

Comment: Maybe because php has normally 60secs of runtime so it will need more time the php code on destination to allow you store the file. With a 512Kb upload in 60 secs you normally can upload up to 5MB of data

Comment: But as soon as the second AJAX function attempts to send the request, the browser crashes and closes the developer console. Any ideas why that'd happen?

Answer (score 0):

I would skip the downloading of the data through AJAX.

If i'm understanding what you're trying to do. You could download the data in your PHP, showing the progress using AJAX. Then within the same PHP code on the backend you could send the data to the next location. You could even send an signal through AJAX to tell your client side code that the download had finished and the sending had begun and have a progress bar for that.

Comment: I can't use the second domains PHP to transfer the data directly - in order for the download to start, randomly generated session variables must be present. I did try this initially, using curl.

Comment: could you save the data to a database or your server temporarily when it is first downloaded, then prompt a second download instead of a send?

Comment: I'm trying to download a file from domain A to the users computer (but not save the file, just store it in a variable), then upload it straight to domain B.